# Bitrix24: I want to create a custom API on On premise version

Tags: bitrix

As title, I want to create custom API path on Bitrix24 (On premise version).
I tried follow Bitrix instructions: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=013764&LESSON_PATH=3913.3516.5062.13764
But can not create.
Please help me!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.